# Google play and play services for Sony Experia T3

Tags: google-play-store

I lost my phone and lost all google apps as a result. Now I want to reinstall Google play and play services. Kindly assist

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Can you give more information? You lost your phone and was able to get it back? Or do you have a new phone? If you got it back, where only Google Play and Play Services that were no longer available? Did you check if they were disabled? Please edit your post and add more details.

Comment: I managed to get the phone back, long after I had bought 2 other phones. Now I want to start using my old phone which has no google play apps save for google. I have tried downloading google play and services, but to no avail.

Comment: Have you checked if they have been disabled in Settings -> Apps, then click the 3-dots followed by show system apps? Is/was your phone rooted?

Comment: The app preferences were reset and th phone is rooted